# Routes not working codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

Routes not working and default controller showing error 404 when I am setting welcome as a default controller then all routes defined with the welcome controller working but my other routes and url not working.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['testRoute'] = 'welcome/test';
$route['testRoute/(:num)'] = 'welcome/test/$i';
```

All above routes are working with only welcome controller.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['loginMe'] = 'login/loginMe';
$route['logout'] = 'user/logout';
```

Showing error 404 for all controllers and functions.

Comment: Could be a number of things... Are your login and user controller files 1st letter uppercase. It might help if you show those.

Comment: All name spaces are correct. Everything in working fine in localhost but on live server except welcome controller for everything its showing error 404.

Comment: what's live servr URL ??

Comment: http://www.missionriev.in/admin/

Comment: So your login Controller is named Login.php and your user controller is named as User.php. So what system is your local development server running on?

Answer (score 11):

If you put index.php after domain this will work.

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/login/
```

You should remove index.php from url by replacing in config and .htaccess

replace in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

by

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Update : 

`$config['index_page'] = '';` . I already had that . `my_website/index.php/my_route` tip worked. Changing .htaccess didn't do anything ( I am using xampp and just transferred my website from Linux to xampp for dev). But then, I changed the .htaccess to a cleaner version and it now shows (removed unnecessary Apache rules )`No input file specified`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. In config.php of config folder, use: `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`
2. Use `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`
3. `Use $config['index_page'] = '';`
4. Also remember to set your base url. Mine is: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/code';`
5. Finally use the following htaccess file:

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /code/index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>`

NB: Remember to edit your path to index.php in the htaccess file. Hope this works for you

Comment: +1 for Htaccess rule. when i move code to live server my htaccess is not moved and i stuck in problem of `404`. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Create the `.htaccess` file in the main directory, and including the following code. Refer to CodeIgniter 3 URLs user guide for more information.

[image: directory structure]

More Info: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

`.htaccess` file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```